# Python - Return all substrings in the first group of nested parentheses

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to find an efficient way to select all the sub-strings contained in the ***first group*** of nested parentheses from a string.

For example:

```
input: a d f gsds ( adsd ) adsdaa    
output: ( adsd )

input: adadsa ( sadad adsads ( adsda ) dsadsa ) ( dsadsad ) 
output: ( sadad adsads ( adsda ) dsadsa )

intput: a ana anan anan ( adad ( sad ) sdada asdad ) ( sadad ( adasd ) asda ) sdafds ( afdasf )
output: ( adad ( sad ) sdada asdad )
```

Notice there could be multiple groups of nested parentheses.

One ***solution*** would be scanning the string `char` by `char` and keeping track of the number of opened parentheses until (decreasing the number, once we have a closing parenthesis) the counter becomes 0 again.

I am wondering if there is a simpler way to do it? Maybe with regular expressions?

Thanks

Comment: You should avoid using `regex`, it could get complicated and error prone. The approach you suggested is your safest bet

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns

Comment: sshashank124's link's tl;dr summary is that you can't use regexes to match arbitrarily deep nested parentheses. Assuming you care about parentheses pairing correctness, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a little function:

```
def parens(s):
    i=s[s.find('('):s.find(')')].count('(')   #counts number of '(' until the first ')'
    groups = s[s.find('('):].split(')')       #splits the string at every ')'
    print ')'.join(groups[:i]) +')'           #joins the list with ')' using the number of counted '('
```

---

Demo:

```
>>> parens('a d f gsds ( adsd ) adsdaa')
( adsd )

>>> parens('adadsa ( sadad adsads ( adsda ) dsadsa ) ( dsadsad )')
( sadad adsads ( adsda ) dsadsa )

>>> parens('a ana anan anan ( adad ( sad ) sdada asdad ) ( sadad ( adasd ) asda ) sdafds ( afdasf )')
( adad ( sad ) sdada asdad )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pyparsing` to select all the sub-strings contained in the first group of nested parentheses from a string.

```py
import pyparsing as pp

pattern = pp.Regex(r'.*?(?=\()') + pp.original_text_for(pp.nested_expr('(', ')'))

txt = 'a d f gsds ( adsd ) adsdaa'
result = pattern.parse_string(txt)[1]
assert result == '( adsd )'

txt = 'adadsa ( sadad adsads ( adsda ) dsadsa ) ( dsadsad )'
result = pattern.parse_string(txt)[1]
assert result == '( sadad adsads ( adsda ) dsadsa )'

txt = 'a ana anan anan ( adad ( sad ) sdada asdad ) ( sadad ( adasd ) asda ) sdafds ( afdasf )'
result = pattern.parse_string(txt)[1]
assert result == '( adad ( sad ) sdada asdad )'
```

* `pyparsing` can be installed by `pip install pyparsing`

##### Note:

If a pair of parentheses gets broken inside `()` (for example `a(b(c)`, `a(b)c)`, etc), an unexpected result is obtained or `IndexError` is raised. So be careful. (See: [Python extract string in a phrase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70953916/python-extract-string-in-a-phrase/70959340#70959340))