# Python Regex: To capture all words within nested parentheses

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to extract all words within nested parentheses by using regex. Here is an example of my `.txt` file:

```
hello ((

(alpha123_4rf)
45beta_Frank))
Red5Great_Sam_Fun
```

I have tried this with regex:

```
r'[\((?\(??(^\()?\))]'
```

but have not been able to get the desired output. I want my output to be like this:

```
((

(alpha123_4rf)
 45beta_Frank))
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: if you want any number of nested parentheses, you'll need subexpression call, but that is not supported by `re` module.. you can use third-party `regex` module though

Comment: @Sundeep hm...what is a third-party `regex` ? sorry, as I am on a newbie level in python

Comment: see https://pypi.org/project/regex/

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12280660/5527985

Comment: yeah, there's a solution in the linked question above with `regex` module.. `regex.findall(r'\((?:[^()]++|(?0))++\)', s)` will work for any level of nesting

Comment: An alternative version using `pyparsing` is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29810464/python-return-all-substrings-in-the-first-group-of-nested-parentheses/70996791#70996791

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern `(?s)\([^(]*\((.+)\)[^)]*\)`

Explanation:

`(?s)` - flag: single line mode - `.` matches also newline character

`\(` - match `(` literally

`[^(]*` - match zero or more characters other from `(`

`\(` - match `(` literally

`(.+)` - match one or mroe of any characters and store it inside first capturing group

`\)` - match `)` literally

`[^)]*` - match zero or more characters other from `)`

`\)` - match `)` literally

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HHJIJj/1)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Michal. It works!

Comment: hey Michal, what if my nested brackets are inconsistent? Lets say I have another that is like this (Select xxxxx, xxxx(xx) as xxxxxx, xxxx(xyzz) as kkk, cas((hello((cas(xxx as abc 'yxys')) as afkk from kjdkj and hsx gkgkg = rate'98209''; ); quit;

Answer (score 0):

If the parantheses are directly following each other, this simpler solution would also do it:

```
def find_brackets(text):
    rx = "(?s)\(\((.+)\)\)"
    z = re.search(rx,text)
    if z: 
        return  z[0] 
    else: 
        return ''
```